# Scala Saving Sort Function Parameters

Tags: function, scala, sorting

I'm trying to save the parameters used to sort a sequence in Scala for deferred execution at a later time.

For example, instead of "list.sortBy (*.value)", I want to save the ("*.value") sort function, and retrieve this sort function ("_.value") at a later time for the actual sorting.

How do I save and retrieve the sort function arguments for deferred execution?  Here is some sample test code:

```
class SortTest {

  def testSort () = {

    val myClass = new MyClass(0)
    val list = List (myClass, new MyClass(1), new MyClass(2), new MyClass(3), new MyClass(4))

    // Want to sort by value attribute, but don't want to sort right away.  Rather
    // how do I save the sort function, and retrieve it at a later time for execution?
    list.sortBy(_.value)

    // save the sort function (i.e. sort by the value attribute of myClass)
    // something similar to the following syntax
    myClass.setSortFunction (_.value)

    // retrieve the sort function and sort the list
    list.sortBy(myClass.getSortFunction())          

  }

  class MyClass (d:Int){
    val value = d
    val sortFunc = null

    // what should be the signature of this function ?
    def setSortFunction (sortFunc: ()) = {
      this.sortFunc = sortFunc
    }

    // what should be the return type of this function?
    def getSortFunction () = {
      return sortFunc
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just assign this function to the variable? Why don't you use lazy collections? What are you trying to accomplish by deferring sorting?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
val sortFunction = (x : { def value: Int } ) => x.value
```

At this point, you might not be happy with the hardcoding of `Int`. Unfortunately, a function *must* have well defined types, so I cannot make this generic on the return type.

One could instead make it a definition:

```
def sortFunction[T] = (x : { def value: T } ) => x.value
```

However, you cannot pass definitions around, only values, and values cannot be parameterized.

On the other hand, you are approaching this the wrong way -- there's an assumption there that `sortBy` takes a function as a parameter, and only that. Not true: `sortBy` takes *two* parameters: a function, and an `Ordering`. If you don't save the ordering, you cannot sort it.

And here we get to the other problem... the function must have a type `MyClass => T`, and the ordering must be of type `Ordering[T]`. Without knowing in advance what `T` is, you cannot save that.

Fortunately, and the reason why `Ordering` is a good idea, you can simply create an `Ordering[MyClass]`, and use that!

Here's how:

```
class MyClass(d: Int) {
  val value = d
  private var sortFunction: Ordering[MyClass] = _
  def setSortFunction[T : Ordering](f: MyClass => T) {
    sortFunction = Ordering by f
  }
  def getSortFunction = sortFunction
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
list.sorted(myClass.getSortFunction)
```

Notice that instead of `sortBy` it uses `sorted`. The method `sortBy` is implemented by creating an `Ordering` and calling `sorted` with it, so you are not losing any performance.